# Get physical file path in unit test running in a domain instead a relative path to the domain

Tags: c#, unit-testing, path

How can I get a physical file instead a domain related path in my unit test?

I am using this code :

```
 var codebase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
 var pathUrlToDllDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(codebase);
 var pathToDllDirectory = new Uri(pathUrlToDllDirectory).LocalPath;
```

What I get is this

file:\compdata\folders$\userA\Documents\Projects\ProjectA\ProjectA.Test\bin\Debug

But I what I expected is somthing like this:

```
C:\windows\userA\Documents\Projects\ProjectA\ProjectA.Test\bin\Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I had created these extensions for the `Assembly` to get those. See if it works for you:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;


public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Returns the full path of the assembly file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetAssemblyPath(this Assembly Assemb)
    {
        string FileName = Assemb.CodeBase;

        if (FileName.Substring(0, 4).ToUpperInvariant() == "FILE")
            FileName = FileName.Remove(0, 8);

        return FileName;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Returns the path to the folder where the assembly file is located
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetAssemblyFolder(this Assembly Assemb)
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(GetAssemblyPath(Assemb));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Combines the assembly folder with the passed filename, returning the full path of that file in the assmebly's folder.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetFileInAssemblyFolder(this Assembly Assemb, string FileName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(GetAssemblyFolder(Assemb), FileName);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Returns the full name of the embedded resources containing the passed string - Match case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Assemb"></param>
    /// <param name="ResourceName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetResourcesContainingString(this Assembly Assemb, string ResourceName)
    {
        return Assemb.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(S => S.Contains(ResourceName));
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Implemented - Returns the full name of the first embedded resource containing the passed string - Match case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Assemb"></param>
    /// <param name="ResourceName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetFirstResourceContainingString(this Assembly Assemb, string ResourceName)
    {
        return Assemb.GetResourcesContainingString(ResourceName).First();
    }
}
```